# Disable Button from being clicked when pressing enter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've got a search box at the top of my master page, and when I am trying to submit form on my content pages, the search button from the masterpage gets executed when hitting enter. It even does it when i'm typing in my content pages textfields and hitting enter..

It seems to be a problem with the form, as i'm only using one that fills the whole master page, but i can't seem to create multiple forms.

Maybe i could just remove the enter function on my search button with javascript, who knows?

Comment: You are using asp.net, can you check the "AcceptButton" property in the designer?

Comment: there is no "AcceptButton" in asp.net web form

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you could do :

```
$('#myButton').removeAttr("onenter");
```

or "onclick" if you use the onclick event to perform your action.

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Comment: But wouldnt that remove my onclick function alltogether? Leaving me with a button that cant be clicked.

Comment: Ok sorry, I don't understand you question... You want to disabled the "enter" keyboard press isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle with Jquery.

1. Change button type submit to button.
2. Write on body keypress jquery, Check if some value is there and keycode is 13 then do AJAX Call.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact problem is when you hit enter on content page, your master page's submit button is getting executed.

For this you don't need to disable button from clicking. Just add your content pages controls and submit button in a panel and assign panels `DefaultButton` property to the submit buttons id on content page.

So when you hit enter on master page, search box code will execute and when you press enter on content page, content page's submit button code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the button you can use jQuery an do something like this:

```
jQuery('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```